# Write system call won't print characters from a register

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls, 32-bit

I want to print AAAA with the following:

```
BITS 32;

;write;
 push 0x41414141;
 pop ecx        ;
 mov eax, 4     ; write is syscall 4 for Ubuntu 32-bit
 mov ebx, 1     ; stdout
 mov edx, 4     ;
 int 0x80       ;

;exit;
 mov eax, 1     ;
 mov ebx, 0     ;
 int 0x80       ;
```

Yet, once assembled and linked this code only exits, no errors, what is wrong ?

Comment: What documentation did you use for `int 80h` call? What does it say about `ecx` argument? (btw, in assembly the ";" means "comment" .. why do you put empty comment on every line? .. you don't have to)

Comment: ecx should contain a pointer to the string. 0x80 means one bit above ascii limit, thus into the OS.

Comment: 0x80 value is 128, which **is** beyond classic 7bit ASCII, as you stated. But that doesn't matter in any way for the `int` instruction, which can call interrupt procedure for any 8 bit number from 0 to 255 (with `int 3` having also special dedicated single byte opcode, used by debuggers for breakpointing), not caring about it relation with ASCII. What it cares about is the interrupt vector table, where the address at element [0x80] must point to some valid handler (in this case linux OS I suppose). If Linux would use 0x41 handler, you would do `int 'A'` instead... :D

Comment: int 80h is the Linux system call.  Putting 4 in EAX tells the system call that is invoked by the interrupt to do a SYS_WRITE function (with ebx serving as the file handle to write to, ecx serving as a pointer to the memory to be written, and edx serving as a count of bytes to write).  I have no idea how the ASCII table is involved in this, except as a fun fact.

Comment: When a key is pressed, electricity goes to the corresponding pin on the cpu which, according to the path followed by the nano-circuits, arranges a stream of bit into a register. The bit number eight is out of the ascii range so 0x80 struck me when I learnt it was the system call. I just finished a book called "Hacking, the art of exploitation" where many things about the stack and registers are explained but still lots of confusion to fight off. btw I could get the code to work. bye.

Comment: @Yvain: first of all, no, the keyboard keys aren't wired directly to CPU pins.  They're wired to a keyboard controller in the keyboard, which has a USB connector (or a PS/2 connector, which is another low-speed serial bus) to eventually get data to the CPU.  Also, scancodes from keypresses aren't ASCII either.  Lastly, 0x80 is just a number.  It is interesting for being `0b10000000` in binary, i.e. it's the first 8-bit number that has the high bit set.  That's special for ASCII, too, but no more relevant than any other thing that happens to be 128.

Comment: @Yvain: on x86 protected mode there's special memory location called IDT (Interrupt Descriptor Table), set by OS. The `int #n` instruction look at IDT[#n*8] memory, where are data in structure describing which ISR (Interrupt Service Routine) has to be called, then the "call_interrupt" is executed. So the number after `int` is just index into look-up table - a generic byte value, the bits don't have any special meaning in this particular case.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for the demystifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix of your code:

```
push 0x41414141 ; put 'AAAA' into stack memory
mov ecx,esp     ; pointer to the 'AAAA'
mov eax, 4      ; write is syscall 4 for 32-bit Linux
mov ebx, 1      ; stdout
mov edx, 4
int 0x80
add esp,4      ; restore stack
```

No explanation, as you should first check what I did ask in comment, then the fix will be either obvious, or you will have to ask about something particular you don't understand...

If you run your original code with `strace ./my_program`, you'd see `write()` return -EFAULT because you passed a bad address.  Always use `strace` to debug programs that make syscalls and don't behave the way you expected.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the difference between a pointer and what it yields, this makes it obvious.